# Is this true: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n-1}$ ??

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Does this equality hold?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n-1}$$

Comment: Yes, they define the same sequence of partial sums.

Comment: @AlexR that is exactly where my uncertainty lies.

Comment: @picaposo You could state that the two series are equivalent in the following sense: "one series coverges if and only if the other series does, and in this case, they both converge to the same value".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we set $u=n+1$.

When $n=1 \Rightarrow u=2$ and when $n \to +\infty \Rightarrow u \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that, by definition
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n=\lim_{N\to+\infty}S_N
$$
where
$$
S_N:=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n\;.
$$

It's clear that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{N}a_{n-1}=S_N-a_N=S_{N-1}\;.
$$
Since $\lim_{N\to+\infty}S_N=\lim_{N\to+\infty}S_{N-1}$ you can conclude they are equal.